# Multiple layout in one Tabactivity

Tags: android

How could I few layout and require to create in one Tabactivity.

I have try the code below but no luck got error.

```
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Sales Order").setIndicator("Sales Order").setContent(R.layout.frm_txn_so_item_list));
```

OK let me explain clearly.

I have a code below, as you can see I have 4 tab layout page. Each of it has it own activity class. I have a button which is belong to cls_so_item_list.class, whenever I am try to call it in my cls_so it always return me null value.

So I have come out an idea, to remove all the tab page(item,product,summary,Report) activity classes then create it one standalone class which is cls_so.

My question is how do I put the layout page inside the tabHost.addTab? Thanks

```
public class cls_so extends TabActivity implements OnClickListener {
    protected TabHost tabHost;

    int intSalesOrderId;
    src_txn_so.cls_so_obj objSalesOrder;
    static final String LIST_ID = "list_id";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        tabHost = getTabHost();

        newTabIntent("Item", null, cls_so_item_list.class);
        newTabIntent("Product",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.so_product),
                cls_so_prd_list.class);
        newTabIntent("Summary",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.so_summary),
                cls_so_summary.class);
        newTabIntent("Report",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.so_report),
                cls_so_summary.class);


        Button btnSOLineDiscount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.txn_so_btn_line_discount);
        btnSOLineDiscount.setOnClickListener(this);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }

    protected void newTabIntent(String label, Drawable icon, Class<?> pageClass) {
        TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(label);
        tabSpec.setIndicator(label, icon);

        Intent SOIntent = new Intent().setClass(this,pageClass);
        SOIntent.putExtra(LIST_ID, -1);

        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, pageClass));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information..?

Comment: How could I few layout and require to create in one Tabactivity ?? what is the meaning of this ? can you please explain?

Comment: 1. Did you try my answer? 2. Did you ever heard of naming convetions for classes? 3. When you want to add information to a question don't post an answer but edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like that. In your main layout, add in the `FrameLayout` with the id of tabcontent an element `<include>` that points on that layout.

In your code you'll have to change it to.

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Sales Order").setIndicator("Sales Order").setContent(R.id.my_included_layout));
```

if you're `<include>` has the id `"@+id/my_included_layout"`